# Python socket server errors upon PyCharm arcpy import - what have I not set up?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, arcgis, arcpy

I am having trouble with setting up my development environment (the latest release Community build of PyCharm).  I have been using the previous version to write python scripts for ArcGIS processing.  To do this you need to import the ArcGIS python API - arcpy.  This has always been fine but now I can't seem to access arcpy directly.

I have the ArcGIS location added to my python path, to my project settings paths and can instantiate an instance of an arcpy object but trying to interact with top level methods or classes generates a socket server error (below).  For example from the interactive prompt:

```
>>    import arcpy - will work
but typing
>>    arcpy. - will instantly generate 


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59487)
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\SocketServer.py", line 653, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\SocketServer.py", line 712, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

However - if I ignore this and instantiate and instance of a map document for example

```
>>import arcpy
>>fullpath = r'C:\Temp\some.mxd'    # where this is a valid ESRI map doc
>> my_mapdoc_object = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullpath)
```

I can now interact with the object.
What am I doing wrong with setting up my environment?

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a docstring issue that PyCharm is tripping over.

Within arcpy, within the docstring of one of the tool functions, there is an escape character, specifically \a, in a data path. If that is corrected, the error goes away.

Comment: +1 this has been annoying me in ArcGIS 10.2.2 + PyCharm for a while.  The offending file was `<install dir>/arcpy/arcpy/interop.py`. Changing the QuickImport & QuickExport  docstrings to raw (r""") strings fixed it for me.